# How to fix column reference within a multidimensional array for custom SUMIF function?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a custom function in GAS that is equivalent to a SUMIF formula and will run through an array that contains a range of data within a google sheet. The function will sum the 'capacity' column when the 'status' column matches entries from a defined range in the sheet.

It worked fine until I rearranged the array to be separated by columns rather than by row. The columns are arranged: Project name, Connection type, Ownership, Country, **Capacity**, **Status**, Technology, Fuel, Commissioning date, Commissioning end date. This is how the array looks now, it is sorted by the columns.

```
[[Azambi Hydro, Budana Hydro, Busanga Hydro, Dilolo Thermal, N'zilo I Hydro], [Embedded, Embedded, Embedded, Embedded, Embedded], [IPP, IPP, IPP, IPP, PPP], [DR Congo, DR Congo, DR Congo, DR Congo, DR Congo], [10.0, 11.0, 240.0, 0.0, 108.0], [Construction, Operating, Planned, Operating, Rehabilitation], [Conventional hydro, Conventional hydro, Conventional hydro, Undecided or unknown, Conventional hydro], [Hydro, Hydro, Hydro, Cogeneration, Hydro], [Sat Dec 01 08:00:00 GMT+00:00 2018, Mon Jan 01 08:00:00 GMT+00:00 1940, Fri Dec 31 08:00:00 GMT+00:00 2021, , Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 GMT+00:00 1953], [, , , , ]]
```

For some reason the function isn't working with the array arranged this way and I can't seem to figure out why.

Full code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var statusColumn = sheet.getSheetByName('Supply Projections').getRange(6,7,9,1).getValues()

var status = statusColumn.map(function (x) { return x[0] });
var status0 = status[0];
var status1 = status[1];
var status2 = status[2];
var status3 = status[3];
var status4 = status[4];
var status5 = status[5];
var status6 = status[6];
var status7 = status[7];
var status8 = status[8];
var statusArray = [status0,status1,status2,status3,status4,status5,status6,status7,status8];


function transpose(data) {

return (data[0] || []).map (function (col , colIndex) {
return data.map (function (row) {
  return row[colIndex];
  });
});
 }


var sheetData = transpose(sheet.getSheetByName('Project 
Selector').getRange('$D$3:M7').getValues())

//SUMIF function
function sumIf(sumColIdx, criteriaColIdx, criteria, data) {
  return data
    .filter(function (row) {
      return row[criteriaColIdx] === criteria
    })
    .reduce(function (acc, row) {
      return acc + row[sumColIdx]
    }, 0)
}

  var capacityStatusSums = statusArray.map(function (criteria) {
    var statusColIdx = 5
    var capacityColIdx = 4
    return sumIf(capacityColIdx, statusColIdx, criteria, sheetData)
  })
```

I think it might be the way I am referencing the position within the array, see statusColIdx = 5 and capacityColIdx = 4. Previously, they referenced the 5th and 4th column within my data range and I assumed it would be the same with the array arranged by columns but I am not sure.

Comment: Not sure what your intention is with the code outside the SUMIF? If the sumif is a custom function it is meant to be used as a (custom) formula in the spreadsheet, right?

Comment: Well my idea is to do all the formulas within the script. Since this will be shared with multiple people, I figured it would be safer not to have formulas floating in the sheet.

Comment: Since we are missing a lot of background (e.g: where is statusArray defined?), all I can say is that colIdx 4 refers to column H in your data and colIdx would thus be column I.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post to show how 'statusArray' is defined.